# Find solution to recurrence: T(N) = 2 T(N/4 + √N) + (√10) N

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

While solving a complex recurrence equation like this `T(N) = 2 T(N/4 + √N) + (√10) N ;T(1) = 1`

I tried to make some change of variables to make it easy and solve it by master theorem but i failed ,so i take the dominant one so it will be:
`T(N) = 2 T(N/4) + (√10) N` so it is `T(N)=Θ(N)`. Is that true or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to unroll recursion or to make a substitution left me nowhere. So the only thing I was able to do is to see that [image] for any sufficiently large `n` (above 64). You can select any number (not just 8), bigger than 4.

So you end up with

[image]

Solving this with [master's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form_3) you see that it falls in the first case with [image].

Therefore the solution is `Θ(N)` which is the same as you wondered.

Comment: That is a very clever approach.